# Error switching between view controllers - Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am building an iPhone app using Storyboard and I had the stupid idea of implementing different view controllers, rather than a single one handling multiple scenes and now all the project is based on this, so it would be too time consuming to rebuild it from scratch. I need to handle view changes from one view controller to another one. I have:

```
-INTROViewController.m
-INTROscene.m (this is a SKScene laid out by the above controller)

-UpgradeViewController.m
```

There is a sprite button in `INTROscene.m` and when I press this, it triggers a notification which is seen by its view controller (`INTROViewController.m`) and this triggers the switch to another view controller (`UpgradeViewController.m`). If I use **Option 1**, even after adding a delay of several seconds in order for the view to appear, it triggers the error below:

**“Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!”**

I’ve found a way of switching view controllers without triggering this error **(Option 2)** but the visual effect is horrible, with a little lag showing an empty screen between the two. Moreover I cannot use any of the nice transitions which are available using `modalTransitionStyle`.

What is the correct way of switching between views?

In my AppDelegate I don’t have a root view controller (and I don’t know how this should be set up). Is that the reason why I get the error? If so, how could I implement it? Cheers!

```
//Option 1 (triggers the error above)
  -(void)TransitionTo_Upgrades_ViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        //Take from INTROViewController to UpgradeViewController 
        UpgradeViewController *controllerUPGRADES = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Upgrades_storyboard"];
        controllerUPGRADES.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self performSelector:@selector(NowGotoUPRADES) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }

    - (void)NowGotoUPRADES
    {
        [self presentViewController:controllerUPGRADES animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

//Option 2 (no error but horrible effect)
-(void)TransitionTo_OPTIONS_ViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
        [self performSelector:@selector(NowGotoOPTIONS) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
- (void)NowGotoOPTIONS
{
        //Take from INTROViewController to UpgradeViewController 
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *DesiredViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Options_storyboard"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:DesiredViewController];
}
```

Comment: Is this a heavily edited version of your code? I don't see how the above would work as you are assigning the view controller instance to a local variable but you're referring to that same variable in another method outside of that scope. Is this just a typo in your sample?

Comment: Did you set up any segues in the storyboard? Also, what is INTROscene? Is that a view controller?

Comment: INTROscene is an SKScene called from INTROViewController via "viewWillLayoutSubviews". No I did not set up any Segues as I have multiple sprite buttons in this scene and each one should take to a different view controller

Comment: This question is unanswerable without and adequate answer to @Acey's question.

Comment: Apologies for the typing mistakes. I have re-edited the code and made it clearer. Thanks!